# MySQL: IF in WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause

My query selects tasks from a MySQL DB. Each task has a group id and if the group is equal 0 it is a private task I want only return, if the task is from the user who runs this query. Hope that makes sense :-)

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.created_by, u.username
FROM (p_tasks AS t)
LEFT JOIN p_groups AS g ON t.group_id = g.id
JOIN p_users AS u ON t.assigned_to_user_id = u.id
WHERE 
 (
   t.assigned_to_user_id = $user_id OR
   t.owner_user_id = $user_id
 )
 AND
 (
   g.priority >= '10' OR
   t.group_id = 0
 )
 AND
 (
   t.status != "approved" AND
   t.status != "closed"
 )
ORDER BY c.name
```

How can I return the tasks with group_id = 0 only for those who had created the tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your query completely, but the part you have described would look something like this.  This assumes you want all public tasks and all private ones assigned to the user or  owned by the user.

```
WHERE  
 ( 
   (t.assigned_to_user_id = $user_id OR t.owner_user_id = $user_id) AND 
   t.group_id = 0  
 ) 
 OR 
 ( 
    t.group_id != 0    
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(group_id <> 0 OR t.owner_user_id = $user_id) AND
t.assigned_to_user_id = $user_id AND
t.status <> "approved" AND
t.status <> "closed"
```

You should be able to construct your where clause without using an IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

I do not full understud what you mean, but like in english, the clear syntax is:

```
where 
(... AND ... AND ...)
or
(... AND ... AND ...)
or
(... AND ... AND ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.created_by, u.username
FROM (p_tasks AS t)
LEFT JOIN p_groups AS g ON t.group_id = g.id
JOIN p_users AS u ON t.assigned_to_user_id = u.id
WHERE 
 (
   t.assigned_to_user_id = $user_id OR
   t.owner_user_id = $user_id
 )
 AND
 (
   g.priority >= '10' OR
   t.group_id = 0
 )
 AND
 (
   t.status != "approved" AND
   t.status != "closed"
 )
 AND 
 (
   (
          t.group_id <> 0
   )
   OR
   (
     t.created_by = $user_id
   )
 )

ORDER BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! I think I get it know.

When I delete `t.group_id = 0` it seems to be what I want :-)
If I am the owner I select the task by `owner_user_id` or `assigned_to_user_id`. If I am not, it doesn't matter if the task is private (`group_id = 0`), because I don't have enough privileges to select/view it.

I'll try that tomorrow.

Thanks again for your help!!